# communicate between angular controller and route controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, communication, directive

index.html

```
<body>
    <div data-form-modal >
         <form>
             <input type='text' name='test'/>
             <input type='submit' value='submit' ng-click='submit()'/>
             //this submit() function is in mainCtrl
         </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

this is my route:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
        controller: 'mainCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'index.html'
    })
        .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

mainCtrl:

```
controller.mainCtrl = function(){
     ...
     $scope.submit = function(){
         alert(1)
     }
}
```

form modal directive:

```
 directive.formModal=function(){
     return {
          ...
     }
 }
```

when I click the submit button, I try to call the submit() function in mainCtrl, but nothing heppend, I think its because the mainCtrl is a route controller and dosen't belong to any scope, and the formModal directive can't access the submit method.

I want the mainCtrl to handle the restful service and the formModal directive handle the form validation, but I dont know how to call method in mainCtrl from the formModal, and what is the relationship between the mainCtrl and the formModalCtrl?

**edited:**

I try to move the restful method to a service, and call the service method in formModal directive controller , it works fine, but I still need to access the mainCtrl in order to update the model so that the view can change accordingly.

Comment: what are `controller` and `directive` objects here? Seems like a strange way to declare a controller and directive... Try declaring your controller as `app.controller('mainCtrl', function () {...});` and see if you can click?

Comment: I use `var controller={};controller.mianCtrl = function(){}` and add it to app module `app.controller(controller)`

Comment: the declaration works fine

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['controllers'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        controller: 'mainCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'index.html'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    }]);

var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
```

Then:

```
// separate file
controllers.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope'
  function ($scope) {
    // do stuff with $scope
  }
]);
```

You can probably do `app.controller('mainCtrl' ...` instead and save a `controllers` variable. I just happened to get this working on my site this way.

Also, make sure you have an `ng-app` of `myApp` enclosing an element with `ng-view` (for routing to work).